# glReadPixels directly to a texture

Tags: ios, opengl-es

- I render a scene (to the default renderbuffer)
- I want to grab a rectangle from this scene and create a texture out of it
- I would like to do it without glReadPixels()ing down to the CPU and then uploading the data back up to the GPU
- Is this possible using OpenGL ES 2.0?
- P.S. - I want to use a POT area of the screen, not some strange shape

Pseudocode of my already-working GPU->CPU->GPU implementation:

```
// Render stuff here

byte *magData = glReadPixels();

// Bind the already-generated texture object
BindTexture(GL_TEXTURE0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, alias);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, MAGWIDTH, MAGHEIGHT, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, magData);
```

Comment: Just for clarification, did you mean "Is this possible if I use OpenGL ES 2.0 instead?" because the code you are using now doesn't look like 2.0 (2.0 would use a shader instead to bind a texture as far as I am aware).

Comment: Why not render your scene to a texture, then use that texture both to cut out your particular area of interest and to display to the screen?

Comment: @BradLarson But he seems to need a copy anyway, so why not copy from the default framebuffer right away? Spares you from displaying a texture. Or did you mean the option to not copy the region of interest in the first place (and do it by other means, like adapting the texcoords or whatever)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [glCopyTexImage2D](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glCopyTexImage2D.xml) to copy from the back buffer:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
glCopyTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, level, internalFormat, x, y, width, height, border);
```

OpenGL ES 2.0 always copies from the back buffer (or front buffer for single-buffered configurations). Using OpenGL ES 3.0, you can specify the source for the copy with:

```
glReadBuffer(GL_BACK);
```

In light of ClayMontgomery's answer (`glCopyTexImage2D` is slow) - you might find using `glCopyTexSubImage2D` with a correctly sized and formatted texture is faster because it writes to the pre-allocated texture instead of allocating a a new buffer each time. If this is still too slow, you should try doing as he suggests and render to a framebuffer (although you'll also need to draw a quad to the screen using the framebuffer's texture to get the same results).

Comment: This is correct, but glReadBuffer() is not supported by OpenGL ES 2.0 (3.0 supports it). All I need to do is glBindTexture and then call glCopyTexImage2D, which always reads from the default renderbuffer. Thanks!

Comment: Ah sorry - I was looking at the ES 3.0 pages, even though I use it in ES 2.0. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You will find that glCopyTexImage2D() is really slow.  The fast way to do what you want is to render directly to the texture as an attachment to an FBO.  This can be done with either OpenGL ES 2.0 or 1.1 (with extensions).  This article explains in detail:

```
http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Render_to_Texture_with_OpenGL_ES
```